# How can i verify if any text is present in text field in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to verify if text field is empty or not. I was using verifyEval command but its throwing an exception. How can i resolve that or is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command verifyNotText against your locator and leave the value field blank. That should verify that there is some text present. If you want to confirm it is blank then it's just the same using verifyText instead.